# Rails global variable after user sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables

I want to set a global variable which I can use in any controllers / views. This variable use some user specific data stored in database so I can't access them before I know the user. I need this variable to be initialize **only after the user sign in process**.

In other words, in my database I store a particular unique ID for every users and when a user sign in, I need to retrieve this ID and use it to create my variable.

How can I manage do to this ? I tried multiples solutions / bypass without success yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a before_action in the application controller, with a condition to check if a user is signed in. Are you using devise? Then it would be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_my_variable

   private

   def set_my_variable
       @my_variable = current_user.my_variable if user_signed_in?
   end
```

Comment: Essentially same as the session, but more secure I think. Good suggestion.

Comment: Yes I'm using devise on this

Comment: OK then my code should work just fine (obviously assuming you change 'my_variable' to the correct name.

Comment: @RichardAE Yes just tried it and it works perfectly. I was trying some other 100x more complicated solutions ... -_- This one is super easy to understand and set up. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the cookie store in Ruby on Rails or the Session. You set these in your controllers and they are available globally after that.

The cookie stores in your clients browser and is ever available after the browser is closed and your connection to the client is gone. This is great for persistent data you wan't between logins, but can be a security risk since the client and anybody with access to their computer can read the cookie values.

The session on the other hand is set for the current time the browser is open on the site. When the browser closes, the session data gets deleted along with it.

So, to store your ID or whatever you need, in your controller you can put it in the session which every controller will have access to from that point on until the browser is closed. Or you can put it in the cookie and you will have access to it as long as the user doesn't clear their cookies mid session or you delete it yourself.

I would suggest the session for sensitive data. You can set it every time you login the user so it should fit your needs.

```
session[:user_id] = "whatever you want"
```

The session hash is available in any controller in your website so by setting a new key such as :user_id, it will add it to the session right away. So, you can create as much as you need wherever you need. Then to access it again, just pull the value.

```
user_id = session[:user_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a bit unclear but I would suggest that you define a method on your user model which fetches whatever it needs to for each individual user. Then you can use current_user helper (I'll just guess you are using devise) to call that method for your current user.